# Flash As3 Streaming player - onBWDone

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming

I got this error when tring to implement Stream connection with meta info

`Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetConnection was unable to invoke callback onBWDone. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onBWDone not found on flash.net.NetConnection and there is no default value.
    at SS4uOpenplayer_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()`

I implemented onBWDone function as like

```
meta.onBWDone=function(meta:Object){

}

meta.onMetaData = function(meta:Object)
{
}
```

But stil am getting the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to attach a "client" object on the NetConnection instance. The client contains references to necessary callback functions.

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{} };
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can write onBWDone in the same class if you make this

nc.client=this