# as3 stream from crtmp-server

Tags: actionscript-3, video

if i am using the mediaplayback component in Adobe flash, the videostream on a crtmp-server runs correctly.

if i try to do this on my own without using that component i got some errors, unluckily there is no much support explaining streaming over as3 without a mediaplayback-component.

i have following code

```html
package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.media.Video;
 import flash.net.NetConnection;
 import flash.net.NetStream;
 
 
 /**
  * ...
  * @author Siam Modi
  */
 public class Main extends MovieClip
 {
  
  public function Main()
  {
   
   var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
   nc.connect("rtmp://213.136.73.230/maya");
   var vid:Video = new Video();
   addChild(vid);
   var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
   
   vid.attachNetStream(ns);
   ns.play("atlas.mp4");
  }
 
 }

}
```

Any ideas ? Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect a `NetStream` to a `NetConnection` instance only after it fires a `NetStatusEvent` with `NetConnection.Connect.Succes` `info.code`.
To get this event you need to call 
`nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler)`
before calling
`nc.connect("rtmp://213.136.73.230/maya");`

and there attach `NetStream` / `Video`:

```
    private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);   
                vid.attachNetStream(ns);
                ns.play("atlas.mp4");

            break;
            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                trace("Stream not found: " + videoURL);
            break;
        }
    }
```

[here is an example from the reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: thats it, thank you...

do you have a solution for the "NetConnection was unable to invoke callback onBWDone" error ?

Comment: @Glowhollow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296822/flash-as3-streaming-player-onbwdone seems to be the solution (`nc.client` property)